# Imagen responsive para web

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy intentando hacer una pagina en la cual añado la imagen  pero no logro hacerla responsive vaya probe con:

```
**.img-responsive{
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
}**
```

pero no nada

Comment: Agrega el HTML donde incrustas la imagen

Comment: ya puede conseguir dar con la solucion estaba en poner la parte del css esto: background-size: cover;

Comment: Publicala entonces como respuesta

Answer (score -1):

ya puede conseguir dar con la solución estaba en poner la parte del css esto: background-size: cover; –

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada